# SQL select city name and length with min & max lengths

Tags: sql, sql-server, having

Here is my SQL Script to get the 2 records only having Min. & Max. length of city

```
SELECT  CITY, LEN(CITY) [Length] 
FROM Addresses 
GROUP BY CITY
HAVING LEN(CITY) IN (MIN(LEN(CITY)), MAX(LEN(CITY)) )
```

Why it is returning all the records?

```
| CITY           |  Length  
-----------------------------
| Delhi          | 5        
| Gautham Nagar  | 13
| Mau            | 3
| New Delhi      | 9
```

It should return only two records with

```
Gautham Nagar  | 13
Mau            | 3
```

Comment: `SELECT CITY, LEN(CITY)
FROM (SELECT  CITY, MIN(LEN(CITY)) OVER() AS MINLength, MAX(LEN(CITY)) OVER() AS MAXLength FROM Addresses) AS A
WHERE LEN(CITY) IN (MINLength, MAXLength)`

Comment: ...with a `GROUP BY CITY` tagged on the end, in case you've got more than one row per city.

Answer (score 0):

This query should do it too:

```sql
SELECT      TOP (1)
            CITY
            , MIN ( LEN ( CITY ) )
                OVER ( ORDER BY LEN ( CITY ) ASC ) AS [Length]
FROM        Addresses
UNION
SELECT      TOP (1)
            CITY
            , MAX ( LEN ( CITY ) )
                OVER ( ORDER BY LEN ( CITY ) DESC ) AS [Length]
FROM        Addresses
ORDER BY    [Length] DESC ;
```

Comment: That query worked for me with the sample data provided. You don't have to have the ORDER BY at the end. I just thought it neatened up the results. And yes, the query by @lptr works just as well.

Comment: You are right, u r using over() function

Answer (score 0):

This is the working solution replied by [lptr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12403612/lptr) in a comment

```
SELECT CITY, LEN(CITY) 
FROM (
    SELECT  
        CITY
      , MIN(LEN(CITY)) OVER() AS MINLength
      , MAX(LEN(CITY)) OVER() AS MAXLength FROM Addresses
    ) AS A 
WHERE LEN(CITY) IN (MINLength, MAXLength)
```